# PostgreSQL PHP-Class

Tags: php, oop, postgresql

The most common databases are working with PHP. PostgreSQL comes also preinstalled with PHP. The problem is, that PostgreSQL only supports procedural programming.
My Questions:

1. Will there be a OOP-Class in a future release of PHP?
2. Do you know a 3rd Party Class ?

Comment: "PostgreSQL only supports procedural programming". Er. It's a relational DBMS. It has limited procedural support via PL/PgSQL, etc, but it mostly supports relational set based queries. Do you mean the PHP driver for PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the PDO PostgreSQL driver.

info:
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-pgsql.php